# Can get relatinship only when using find() , can't where using where()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've some problem i can't understand:

I have many-to-many relationship model, if i use `::find(x)` it's working alright, but if i use `::where()` i get

`Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$dlists`

Here's my code:

```
$employee = Employee::whereUsername('xyz')->get();
$lists = $employee->dlists;
```

returns the error.

```
$employee = Employee::find(1);
$lists = $employee->dlists;
```

returns the needed output.

what am i mising?

Comment: It's because the query returns a `Eloquent Collection`, if the usernames are unique you can call `whereUsername('xyz')->first()` then you get an `Employee Object` where you will have access to `dlists`.

Comment: Please post your comments as answer so i can mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the query returns a `Eloquent Collection`, if the usernames are unique you can call `whereUsername('xyz')->first()` then you get an `Employee Object` where you will have access to `dlists`.